# dequeueReusableCell Overlapping Buttons/Using protocols with Custom Classes

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates, cell

I am working on a project which uses a table view controller. Within each table view cell, there is a UILabel and a custom segmented control. I have constructed the custom segmented control as well as the UILabel in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Unfortunately, due to cell reuse, new segmented controls and UILabels are created over pre-existing ones, resulting in multiple overlapping segmented controls and UILabels in each cell. Obviously, this is a significant memory problem that would culminate in the app crashing.

The code for cellForRowAtIndexPath looks like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath)


    let nameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Sample Item"
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    let actionButton = YSSegmentedControl(
        frame: CGRect.zero,
        titles: [
            "No",
            "Yes"
        ])
```

The most viable solution would be to create a custom cell class and then simply create the segmented control and UILabel in there. However, due to the fact that the segmented control is custom and uses a delegate to exchange information between its code and the TableViewController, I'm having difficulty. The delegate is supposed to access the custom cell class and output the selected index of the segmented control (i.e. "0" for option 0 and "1" for option 1) however I cannot get this to work.

Here is the code I'm trying to use to create the custom cell class (where MyCell is the custom class and `extension MyCell` is part of the delegate.

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell{


override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    setupViews()

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}


let nameLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Sample Item"
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

let actionButton = YSSegmentedControl(
    frame: CGRect.zero,
    titles: [
        "Yes",
        "No"
    ])

func setupViews(){


    addSubview(nameLabel)
    addSubview(actionButton)
    actionButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-16-[v0]-160-[v1]-16-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": nameLabel, "v1": actionButton]));
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": nameLabel]))
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-60-[v0]-60-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": actionButton]))

}
}

var tagToIndex = [1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0]

extension MyCell: YSSegmentedControlDelegate {
func segmentedControl(_ segmentedControl: YSSegmentedControl, willPressItemAt index: Int) {
    print(index)
}

func segmentedControl(_ segmentedControl: YSSegmentedControl, didPressItemAt index: Int) {

}
```

}

**Additional Information**

I must have a way to get a handle on the index of the cell that the segmented control is in. Currently each segmented control has a tag attached to it that corresponds to the row. I am open to other ways of accessing the Row Index (i.e. through delegation) if anyone has any suggestions.

Here's a picture of the app just to make things a little more clear

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezMUJ.png

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest method of knowing whether to create a new label and segmented view is to have a subclass that only specifies whether the cell has been drawn on using a Boolean like "var viewsAdded = false".

Just make sure to register the custom cell class you make using:

```swift
func register(_ cellClass: AnyClass?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String)
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614888-register